# Navigating to a view controller modally and then navigation using push segue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, push

I have 2 storyboards. I have a situation where I have to navigate from a view controller1 in storyboard 1 to a view controller2 in storyboard 2. The view controller 1 is added as a subview to a parent view controller. When I click on a row in a table view in view controller 1, I have to navigate to storyboard 2.

Initially it was not detecting a touch in the table row. I managed handling it by using a single tap gesture. Now when I click on a row, I am able to navigate to storyboard2 viewcontroller 2 modally. But after navigating ,I am not able to move anywhere on a button click in view controller 2 because it uses all push segues there.

Here is the sample code which I used to navigate.

```
 *NSString * storyboardName = @"OppotunityStoryboard";
  NSString * viewControllerID = @"AgreementMainViewController";

 UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
 AgreementMainViewController *controller = (AgreementMainViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
 controller.productTransactionentity = productTransactionEntity;
 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];*
```

Comment: Check whether the IBOutlet connection established properly..

Comment: I am doing it programatically Kumar. So, I guess the Outlet connections should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed ViewController 2 in a navigation controller in order for it to be able to use push segues when presented modally.

Comment: Adam: I tried that.I embedded a navigation controller for that It still does not navigate in viewcontroller2 when I have a push segue. It is navigating for modal segues in the same view controller. Could you please advice what could be the issue? Thanks!